# Handling One-to-Many relationship view?

Tags: views, entities

I am trying to learn Drupal, and getting stuck every hour. I wish someone could walk me through this. I am trying to create a Employee-Company relationship. I have created a Company Content Type with just Name, Address and Telephone Numbers. And a Employee with Name and an Entity Reference to Company and multi-value Term Reference to skill set.

Now in my page skill/[whatever_the_skill_may_be] - I get a list of Employee. This happens automatically. Now I want to show the Company information along with each employee, but surprisingly can't seem to do this easily. I get the Company name which can be linked, but not the address or Telephone number.

Some of the pages I searched for the answer seem to suggest creating a View for this. I am not sure if I really need to, for such a simple requirement. But even if I do so, how do I override the default view of skill/[whatever_the_skill_may_be], and also the employee/[name-of-employee] page, where I would like to show the company information?

I hope I am not asking a stupid or very obvious question. Thanking u in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Its simple, follow the steps.

1. Create a view of employees.
2. In the **Format** section show **fields** instead of **content**
3. Add the fields, Employee Name, Skill, Company Name
4. Add a **Contextual Filter**, `Content: Has taxonomy term ID`

   - Provide default value as **Taxonomy term Id from URL**
   - Select **Specify validaion criteria**

     - Select the validator **Taxonomy term** and choose your **vocabulary - Skillset**
     - In **filter value type**, select **Term name converted to Term ID**
5. Add a relationship **Entity Reference: Referenced Entity**
6. Now add the fields, **Phone**, **Address**, but make sure you are selecting the relationship that you added.

Comment: wolverine...how do I override the default pages?

Comment: @Nandini I've posted an answer which describes the best practice to do that, which is already provided by Views.

Comment: You can't do it to the default page, but views by default provide one view to mimic the core page, that view will be named **Taxonomy Term**, enable that view and follow  my answer from **Step 5**

Answer (score 0):

You need Views to achieve that. The listing you are getting automatically is provided by Drupal core and it is meant only for simple listing of teasers of content.

Views module provides already an override for the core taxonomy listing. You just need to enable it and adjust for your needs.

To do that:

1. Download and enable [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), if you haven't already done.
2. Go to views administration at `admin/structure/views`
3. Enable the view named **Taxonomy Term** and edit it.
4. You need to add a relationship to the **Company**. To do that:

   - Expand the **Advanced** section
   - Add new relationship under **Relationships** and select **Entity Reference: Referenced Entity** with a description like *A bridge to the Content entity that is referenced via FIELD_YOUR_REFERENCE_FIELD*
   - Now you need to change the **Teaser** to **Fields** under **Format**.
   - You can now add the fields from the **Employee** content type AND **Company** content type which is referenced by the Employee.